# Swift timer won't stop

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, counter

Code:

```
var timerCount: Int = 15

hideTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
    self.timerCount -= 1
    print(self.timerCount)
    if self.timerCount <= 0 {
        if self.hideTimer != nil {
            self.hideTimer.invalidate()
            self.hideTimer = nil
        }
    }
})
```

print statement just keeps on printing into negative numbers =(

This is happening within a UITableViewCell, if that matters.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You get a reference to the timer in the callback: '(timer)'.
Use this one to invalidate your timer:

```
var timerCount: Int = 3

let hideTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
    timerCount -= 1
    print(timerCount)
    if timerCount <= 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
})
```